# Create an "accessory view" in Java Swing file dialogs

Tags: java, swing, native

On Mac OS X, the native [NSSavePanel](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSSavePanel_Class/Reference/Reference.html) supports an "accessory view" that can be used to specify file types and other options (using `setAccessoryView:`). I would like to do something similar in my Swing application as well.

[image: Accessory view on OS X]

I know [JFileChooser](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFileChooser.html) supports something like this but it just doesn't look native. Is it possible to do this using AWT's [FileDialog](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/FileDialog.html) directly (which does use the native file dialog)? Maybe using [Java Native Access](https://github.com/twall/jna)?

Comment: See also [MacWidgets](http://code.google.com/p/macwidgets/).

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not possible with FileDialog.  Check out [QuaQua](http://www.randelshofer.ch/quaqua/guide/index.html).  It's a Mac OS X Java look-and-feel that more closely matches the native UI.  Its version of JFileChooser may be more to your liking.

If you're already familiar with the OS X API though, the best solution may be to just open a native dialog directly via JNI.